C# .Net Core Compile only one appsettings.json
In my application often I have three files of settings:

appsettings.json
appsettings.Development.json
appsettings.Production.json

When I publish, all three files are brought into the publish folder. Nothing wrong, it's the classic behavior. My question is: is there a possible way to generate a unique appsettings.json file with the content of appsettings.{CurrentEvironment}.json based on publish mode (Debug or Release)? Possibly without using the Post-build event in Visual Studio.

There's no reason to create a single file and a large number of reasons not to. There's nothing special about those files, they're just one of multiple settings sources that are used by default, including command line arguments and environment variables, all of which override the settings from the JSON files. They're only copied to the publish folder because they're marked as Content and have the Copy Always or Copy If Newer setting. That can change. In the csproj file, you can put those Content elements in an ItemGroup with a condition that only applies on Debug or Release
